# Upload Photos Facebook api EVERYONE

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I'm working with fql and php sdk and I created a Facebook page and I want to allow all users who likes my pages to upload photos (created dynamic from different photos like a collage), my problem is that as administrator of the page I can upload pictures but as a normal user does not allow me:

There is some kind of rule that does not allow me to upload photos

```
public static function AddPhotoToAlbum ($ userId, $ message)
{
$albumID = '166X93X634658X2 ';

$facebook-> setFileUploadSupport (true);

                $ file = "@". realpath ('img / image'. $ userId.. 'png');

$args = array (
'message' => $ message,
'access_token' => $ accessToken,
'image' => $ file);

$data = $ facebook-> api ('/'.$ album. '/ photos', 'post', $ args);

print_r ($ data);
```

}

Any idea how to solve this problem. regards

Comment: where is the album ID coming from? is this a user or page album? Is the access token for a user or the page?

Comment: Is your app in a Sandbox mode? what's your page settings? are users allowed to publish and upload photos?

Comment: the album id come from the page album and the access token is the user logged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When uploading with graph API make sure you use album's object_id and not aid (album id) - they are different. Strange it works for you though in some scenarios as you say. Also it would be helpful if you copy-paste the error message you get from facebook API here.

hope this helps

EDIT: user has to be administrator of the page to be able to upload.

Comment: Hi Anatoly thanks for your answer but didn't work i'm not sure about if i can push photos to page's album, atm im not getting any kind of error. This it's driving me crazy